# Return an array of arrays of key-value pairs WITHOUT using Object.entries()

Tags: javascript, sub-array

I am trying to write a function that accepts an object and returns an array of arrays of key-value pairs. I also cannot use the `Object.entries()` function.

Example: For `var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };` I would want to return: `[["a",1], ["b",2], ["c",3]]`

Here is what I have written so far:

```js
function entries(obj) {

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return [Number(key), obj[key]];
});
}
console.log(
  entries(obj = {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0})
  );
```

However, I can only get it to return undefined at this point. What exactly am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: You forgot to `return` inside the `entries` function. You also shouldn't use `Number(key)`, that'll result in `NaN` for keys that can't be cast to numbers, like `'a'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple for loop

```js
var obj= {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0}
var arr=[]
for(var item in obj){
  arr.push([item,obj[item]])
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's analyse your code and detect some mistakes and then we will focus on the solution.

```js
function entries(obj) {
  var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return [Number(key), obj[key]];
  });
}
console.log(
  entries(obj = {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0})
);
```

In your code the function `entries` does not return any value. Therefore, the `console.log()` will return `undefined`. We can fix this replacing `var result =` with `return`. So now your `entries` function returns an array based on your object `obj`. Like this:

```js
function entries(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return [Number(key), obj[key]];
  });
}
console.log(
  entries(obj = {
    "1": 5,
    "2": 7,
    "3": 0,
    "4": 0,
    "5": 0,
    "6": 0,
    "7": 0,
    "8": 0,
    "9": 0,
    "10": 0,
    "11": 0,
    "12": 0
  })
);
```

Now we can optimize a little bit let's define a two objects: `objA` and `objB`. the first one will be your first example.

```js
let objA = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
let objB = {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0};
```

If you call `console.log(entries(objA))` you wil get an `NaN` error because the `a` is not a number and you are using the `Number()` method to cast the `key` values. Let's removed that function call. Thi will be final version of the solution:

```js
let objA = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
let objB = {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0};

function entries(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return [key, obj[key]];
  });
}

console.log(entries(objA));
console.log(entries(objB));
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return final `result` from `entries()`

```js
function entries(obj) {
  var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
      return [Number(key), obj[key]];
    });
    return result;
}
console.log(
  entries(obj = {"1":5,"2":7,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0})
  );
```